# JPA with Hibernate issue when persisting Entities with one-one relationship between them

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two tables - bill & billSimpleentry and two corresponding Entity classes Bill & BillSimpleEntry.

Bill and BillSimpleentry have a one-one relationship. Each bill has one billsimpleentry. So billsimplementry.billId has the same corresponding value of bill.id.

SQL structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `bill` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  .....
  .....
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  KEY `fk_bill_groups1_idx` (`groupId`),
  KEY `fk_bill_user1_idx` (`billPayerId`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bill_groups` FOREIGN KEY (`groupId`) REFERENCES `groups` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bill_user` FOREIGN KEY (`billPayerId`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

CREATE TABLE `billsimpleentry` (
  `itemTitle` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itemDescription` text,
  `billId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`billId`),
  KEY `fk_bill_idx` (`billId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

So when a new 'bill' object is persisted, it should also create a billsimpleentry row in the database.

```
save(Bill newBill){
em.persist(newBill);
}
```

Bill class structure:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bill")
public class Bill implements GenericObject {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5660869020353250221L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    ....
    private Long groupId;
    private BigDecimal  billTotal;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private BillSimpleEntry billSimpleEntry;
   ... getters & setters...
}
```

BillSimpleEntry:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="billsimpleentry")
public class BillSimpleEntry  implements GenericObject{

    @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
        private Long billId;
        @Column(columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String itemDescription;


         @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="billSimpleEntryId",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<SimpleUserIdAndLiableCost> simpleUserIdAndLiableCost = new ArrayList<SimpleUserIdAndLiableCost>();
        ... getters & setters...

}
```

Here is the newBill obj data that is attempted to be persisted

```
{
   "id":null,
   "title":"",
   "billDate":null,
   "billPayerId":6,
   "notes":null,
   "billCreaterId":null,
   "groupId":3,
   "billTotal":null,
   "billSimpleEntry":{
      "billId":null,
      "itemDescription":null,
      "simpleUserIdAndLiableCost":[
         {
            "userId":6,
            "liableCost":"50",
            "id":null,
            "billSimpleEntryId":null,
            "user":{
               "id":null,
               "fName":"doe",
               "lName":"doe"
            },
            "isActive":true
         },
         {
            "userId":7,
            "liableCost":"50",
            "id":null,
            "billSimpleEntryId":null,
            "user":{
               "id":null,
               "fName":"doe",
               "lName":"doe"
            },
            "isActive":true
         },
         {
            "userId":8,
            "liableCost":"50",
            "id":null,
            "billSimpleEntryId":null,
            "user":{
               "id":null,
               "fName":"doe",
               "lName":"doe"
            },
            "isActive":true
         }
      ],
      "itemDescriptionId":2
   },
   "billItemEntry":[

   ],
   "userId":null
}
```

But the problem is that em.persist(Bill) fails because billsimpleentry.billId value needs to be populated to the same value as of bill.id. How should I fix this problem? It appears like I need to update my table structure or the table auto id generation strategy. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is your BillSimpleEntry created and linked to newBill? Show the code please.

Comment: @baltov the newBill is an instance of Bill class. Bill class has an attribute billSimpleEntry of type BillSimpleEntry. So the newBill also holds the attribute billsimpleentry. Does that make sense? I also edited the original post to show the contents of newBill.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I need more clarification. I don't know how you create that JSON, but in them is this *"billId":null*. You need to set the parent ID. So, if  that is JSON, process it before persist and attach parent ID to it. Save or persist should not attach parent id to childs automatically.

Comment: The JSON is created programatically in the frontEnd when user fills in a form. I intentionally set billId to null as I thought that JPA will take care of it by delegating the id generation to the database. But if I have to set the billId ahead of time, wouldn't that be wrong as I'm now setting the ids instead of the database?